# select of alternative route reduces zoom

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, tabs, zooming, directions

I'm using google maps api v3 and jquery mobile. I have a page where tab1 shows the map with the route and tab2 shows the route details (setPanel) . When i call setDirections for the response everything works great. The map is centered and the zoom is correct too. When i navigate to the details and select an alternative route and press tab1 to return to the map to see the new route, the zoom is off. Why does this happen? Can i do something to make it work?

Comment: code http://jsfiddle.net/bujar/LaYQJ/10/
1.press button
2. see map
3. press routes
4. select the second route
5. press map
zoom is out

Comment: You  could create your own `panTo` code for click handlers from the directions result if you wanted to parse your own route html. Each point on route has lat/lng provided in results

Comment: Yes i know that, but i want to know if there is an easier way to do things and keep functionality that is already provided. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the directions are changed (to the alternate route) while the map is not displayed, it has the wrong size (its size is reported to the API as zero when it is hidden).  You need to trigger the ["resize" event on the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) after it has been displayed.

from the documentation:

> resize - Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize').

UPDATE:
Looks like the directions_changed event doesn't fire when the map is hidden and the bounds is not set.  Setting the bounds manually when the map is displayed seems to work.

```
function refresh(map) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  var routeIndex = globVars.directionsDisplay.getRouteIndex();
  var routes  = globVars.directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes;
  globVars.map.fitBounds(routes[routeIndex].bounds);    
  alert('resize');                    
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msNAb/10/)

Comment: I've thought that case of zero size but i couldn't be sure. I do trigger the resize event (see refresh). I've added an alert when the resize is triggered http://jsfiddle.net/bujar/LaYQJ/. Is there anything else i'm missing or i have to do it manually?

Comment: Once again thank you so much. If i'm not being too greedy could you help with some insight to the second part of my post? If you can, please update your post in order to select it as the answer and close the topic (or is it better to create a new topic?).

Comment: The only way I know to change the formatting from the existing is to build the sidebar yourself (as you already answered for yourself).  It would be better to create a new topic for other options or ideas on how to do that.