# Google Maps: Embedding multiple locations and directions on a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a mobile app for a medical clinic that has 4 offices/buildings. I'd like to create a Google map that marks all 4 locations, and gives the user option to get directions to each location.

I'm building this app in Phonegap and Jquery mobile. The closest thing I have found so far is this: [Direction example](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#directions_map) .

I would also like the "from" field default to user's location if GPS is enabled or using geolocation.

What are the common practices to do this (from usability point of view)? And do you know any resources I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using gps in your project you can use the code below

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( 

    function (position) {  

    // Did we get the position correctly?
    // alert (position.coords.latitude);

    // To see everything available in the position.coords array:
    // for (key in position.coords) {alert(key)}

    mapServiceProvider(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

    }, 
    // next function is the error callback
    function (error)
    {
        switch(error.code) 
        {
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert ('Timeout');
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                alert ('Position unavailable');
                break;
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert ('Permission denied');
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                alert ('Unknown error');
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Which can be found [here](http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation) or the [phonegap docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition)
When you have the location you can change the value of
your form. Then there is the question of using a plugin
of google maps or not. Personally i didn't use any. Since
you are using jquery mobile you can use [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) .

Create the map in the init event (so you create only once) and 
trigger the resize event in the pageshow event so you will not have problems
with the map appearing on the upper left corner of your screen etc.
If you use the plugin I mentioned, look for the refresh method.
The container of the map must have a size. If it doesn't it 
will not show properly because jqm will give the minimum size
to the container. You can do it programmatically (check for
window height and width) and calculating the space (if there is
a header you have to include it in the calculation).
Finally if you are having problems with zoom look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034724/select-of-alternative-route-reduces-zoom)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: If this answered your question, why don't you accept it? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post about [Google Maps inside jQuery Mobile](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/google-maps-inside-jquery-mobile). I think this solves your issue.